# How to filter for specific Goal Metric event in Firebase's A/B Testing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I am setting up an A/B Test in Firebase for my Android app and my data is coming via Google Analytics into Firebase.

Now, I want to filter for a specific event as the Goal Metric for this A/B test but there is no option to do this. I have 1000's of events, so I need to filter. **How to do this?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firebase ABT supports search for the goal metric, start typing the goal metric search box and it will filter